# How to convert a charAtIndex of string to ASCII equivalent int value

Tags: string, go, golang-migrate

I have a set of strings (ASCII), that I want to assign to a string array (of cap 128).
The position of the string in the array is decided by the ASCII value of the first char of the string.
Like..

```golang
strArr := [128]string{}
strA := "A string"
strB := "B string"
strArr[65] = strA // since strA started with 'A' & ASCII('A') = 65
strArr[66] = strB // since strB started with 'B' & ASCII('B') = 66
```

There is one solution of using `utf8` package, like ...

```golang
r, _ := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(strA)
strArr[r] = strA
```

### Is it possible to time optimise this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can be certain your strings are not empty and their first rune is in the range of `0..127`, you may simply do:

```
strArr[strA[0]] = strA
strArr[strB[0]] = strB
```

Because indexing strings indexes their UTF-8 encoded bytes (this is how Go stores strings in memory), and runes in the range of `0..127` map to bytes 1-to-1, so the first byte is the value of the first `rune`.

Of course if `strA` or `strB` would be empty or their first rune would not fall in the range of `0..127`, the above code would panic.

You can avoid the panic by checking the string and its first byte prior, e.g.:

```
func set(s string) {
    if s == "" || s[0] > 127 {
        return
    }
    strArr[s[0]] = s
}
```

This `set()` function indexes the `s` string twice (first when checking if the first rune / byte is in the valid range, next when indexing the `strArr`). We may store the result of the first indexing and reuse that in the second case, which may or may not give a performance improvement:

```
func set2(s string) {
    if s != "" {
        return
    }
    if first := s[0]; first <= 127 {
        strArr[first] = s
    }
}
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FswM4Au7d5y).